# Iframe with no proper URL in src

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have limited knowledge on IFrames. So far I know that the "src" of an IFrame should have an URL from where the content will be fetched. But lately, I am seeing many IFrames whose contents are as follows:

```
<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/20346936/skysports/homepage_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/20346936/skysports/homepage_0" width="728" height="90" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; height: 90px;"></iframe>
```

Now if we look into the "src" attribute its

```
src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;"
```

So what does this mean and how are much Iframes populated. Any knowledge or pointer would be much appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It's injecting content to iframe.

There is good articles about that:

- [INJECTING HTML INTO AN IFRAME](http://softwareas.com/injecting-html-into-an-iframe/)
- [Inject Content into a new IFrame](https://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/)
- [How to Inject Custom HTML and CSS into an iFrame](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhODHoaats0) (video)

Simple example:

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="main">
    <iframe id="iframe1">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

---

```
#iframe1 {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 80%;
    max-height: 80%;
    color: red;
    padding-top: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**JS**

---

```
$('#iframe1').contents().find('html').html("<h1 style='text-align: center;'>This IS an iframe</h1>");
```

Result

---

[image]